# Область видимости переменной в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Помогите передать координаты курсора из функции mouseMove, переменные curx, cury которые объявлены глобально, не изменяют значения в функции. Вернее получается что в функции объявляются локальные переменные curx, cury, и их значения можно использвать только внутри функции.

```
function createImage() 
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
    var curx;
    var cury;
    canvas.onmousemove = mouseMove;
    function mouseMove(event){ 
    curx=event.pageX-8;
    cury=event.pageY-8;

    }
    document.getElementById('mouseX').value=curx;
    document.getElementById('mouseY').value=cury;
}
```

Comment: а если не делать ``var curx;``/``var cury;``?

Comment: Тогда вообще ничего не выводится, даже что значение не определено, всмысле undefined

Comment: вот я туплю, вы же функцию `createImage()`, в которой происходит 

    document.getElementById('mouseX').value=curx;
    document.getElementById('mouseY').value=cury;

вызываете единожды и когда вызывается `mouseMove` этот участок кода не выполняется, воспользуйтесь ответом @Photon

Comment: Почему единожды, я название просто оставил createImage()

Comment: И все равно хотя бы один раз функция должна передать координаты

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы не перенести вот это:

```
document.getElementById('mouseX').value=curx;
document.getElementById('mouseY').value=cury;
```

внутрь функции mouseMove?

Comment: Дальше идет много функций где используются координаты мыши, и не отелось бы их все переносить в mouseMove

Comment: а что мешает навесить несколько обработчиков через `addEventListener`?

Comment: А вы бы не могли написать пример такого обработчика, что бы он передавал координаты курсора мыши

Comment: сейчас, пожалуй не смогу - я на работе работаю работу(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
function mouseMove(event){ 
    curx=event.pageX-8;
    cury=event.pageY-8;
    return { x: curx, y: cury };
}
```

Comment: Также выводит undefined

Comment: @DreamChild, а где вы видели обработчики событий, которые возвращали бы значение?

Comment: ну неправда  же. 
у меня внешняя функция получает в результате вызова внутренней  вполне валидный объект. Вопрос в том, что передавать внутренней функции в качестве event

Comment: и где же вы увидели "вызов внутренней функции"? `mouseMove()` или `canvas.onmousemove()`?

Comment: Спасибо всем, решил вот так-вот
function LoadS() 
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
    var curx;
    var cury;
    canvas.onmousemove = mouseMove;

    function mouseMove(event){ 
    curx=event.pageX-8;
    cury=event.pageY-8;
    build();
   }

   function build(){
   document.getElementById('a').value=curx;
   document.getElementById('b').value=cury;
   // ну и тут дальше вызываются все остальные функции
   }
}

Comment: Spectre, я не являюсь знатоком JavaScript. На то что здесь идет речь об обработчике события, я, признаться, не обратил внимания. Поэтому и сказал, что это "вызов внутренней функции", уж извините, что задел вашу тонкую душевную организацию, ей-богу, не со зла, а по невнимательности.

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/gwJKa/2/

работает так:

- создается объект-кеш, в котором соответственно хранятся данные. Практично :-)
- создается локальная    функция `writer` (1), которую будем вызывать из функции `mouseMove` (2), (2) которая будет обновлять позицию мышки в переменных и (1) которая будет брать позицию из переменных и заносить их в инпуты.

По идее ничего не должно уйти наружу :-)

Comment: передавать в функцию аргументы и не использовать - круто:

    var writer = function(x,y) {
        cache['mouseX'].value=curx;
        cache['mouseY'].value=cury;        
    }

>По идее ничего не должно уйти наружу :-)

не считая глобальных `curx`, `cury`

Comment: @Spectre это фича :D обновил: http://jsfiddle.net/gwJKa/3/ Вообще да, криво написал, и с mouseMove косяк. Надо бы переписать, если по хорошему.